# How to actually delete files in Iceberg

Tags: apache-iceberg

I know that in Apache Iceberg I can set limits on number and age of snapshots, and that "deleting" data from the table does not result in underlying data removal, it simply masks or deletes tracking information.

I would like to actually delete the underlying files on delete, however. I know this will make time-travel inconsistent, but it is still a business requirement.

https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration/

As best as I can tell, I'll have to track and manage the physical life-cycle every file independently. Am I missing something?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming problem. I'm guessing https://serverfault.com/ would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

We often need an asynchronous task to delete and expire snapshots\data.

If you use spark, you can use https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-procedures/#expire_snapshots, as shay said.

You can also do this using the Java API provided by Apache https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/api/.

Starting a task for each table is difficult to manage. Tables often have different TTL. In this case, You can add custom configurations to a table. Manually scan all iceberg tables, then determines whether to delete expired snapshots and data based on these configurations.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about table history (or time travel) you can simply call the [`expire_snapshots`](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-procedures/#expire_snapshots) procedure after each delete.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Iceberg with Hive (4.0.0-alpha2 + version), you can try expire_snapshot command on beeline.
Like

```
ALTER TABLE test_table EXECUTE expire_snapshots('2021-12-09 05:39:18.689000000');
```

Can read:
https://docs.cloudera.com/cdw-runtime/cloud/iceberg-how-to/topics/iceberg-expiring-snapshots.html

Hive Jira adding support:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-26354